How to calculate the following integral related to the exp function multiply the Q function?
Recently, I have encountered a very difficult integral problem that is related to both exponential function and the normal distribution function. I have been searching for relevant solutions for a long time, but I haven't found any useful information. Therefore, I hope that you, as experts, can provide me with some effective suggestions.
The integral can be written in the following form:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{0}\exp(-at^{2}+bt)\mathrm{Q}(t)dt,
$$
where $\mathrm{Q}(\cdot)=1-\Phi(\cdot)$ with $\Phi(\cdot)$ the cumulative distribution function (CDF) of the standard normal distribution.
Here, I found some useful results that might help solving the above integral.
$$
\mathrm{Q}(x)=\frac{1}{2} \operatorname{erfc}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}\right),
$$
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp \left(-a t^2+b t\right) \operatorname{erfc}(t) d t=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}} \exp \left(\frac{b^2}{4 a}\right) \operatorname{erfc}\left(\frac{b}{\sqrt{a(a+1)}}\right)
$$

If you write $$Q(x)=\frac{1}{2}\text{erfc}\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{2}}\right)=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\text{erf}\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$$
completing the square and assuming $a>0$
$$\frac 12 \int_{-\infty}^0 e^{-a t^2+b t}\,dt=\frac 14 \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}\,e^{\frac{b^2}{4 a}}\,\text{erfc}\left(\frac{b}{2\sqrt{a}}\right)$$
This is the easy part.
Now, for the second part
$$\frac 12 \int_{-\infty}^0 e^{-a t^2+b t}\,\text{erf}\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\,dt$$ if you are optimisitic expand around $b=0$ to face
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{b^n}{2 n!}\int_{-\infty}^0 e^{-a t^2}\,t^n\,\text{erf}\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\,dt$$
and, if
$$J_n=\int_{-\infty}^0 e^{-a t^2}\,t^n\,\text{erf}\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\,dt$$ then
$$J_n=\frac {(-1)^{n+1}} { a^{\frac{n+2}{2}}\sqrt{2 \pi } }\,\,\Gamma \left(\frac{n+2}{2}\right)\,\,\,
   _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{n+2}{2};\frac{3}{2};-\frac{1}{2 a}\right)$$
Recall that
$$\Gamma \left(\frac{n+2}{2}\right)\,\,\,
   _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{n+2}{2};\frac{3}{2};x\right)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\Gamma
   \left(k+\frac{n}{2}+1\right)}{(2
   k+1) \Gamma (k+1)}\,x^k$$
This could converge quite fast. Computing the partial sums for $a=b=1$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 p & \sum_{n=0}^p J_n \\
 0 & -0.1736236 \\
 1 & -0.0292861 \\
 2 & -0.1059371 \\
 3 & -0.0738621 \\
 4 & -0.0852905 \\
 5 & -0.0816820 \\
 6 & -0.0827165 \\
 7 & -0.0824428 \\
 8 & -0.0825104 \\
 9 & -0.0824947 \\
 10 & -0.0824982 \\
 11 & -0.0824974 \\
 12 & -0.0824976 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Thank you very much for your nice and generous answer, I will read your answer carefully! Thank you very much!
